# decoding API in PHP, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, decode

please could someone explain the below to me and why it doesn't work, i am new to coding. why does my php return single value from what it receives from the API, but my javascript tries to access more than that? Why is it that when i click on the button, it does not display results on the page? how do i allow users to input values for each API?

i am using this API,  http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?formatted=true&lat=47.03&lng=10.2&username=flightltd

here is the coding in PHP

```
<?php

// remove for production

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$url='http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON? 
formatted=true&lat=47.03&lng=10.2&username=flightltd';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result,true);    

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " 
ms";
$output['data'] = $decode['countryCode'];

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($output);
```

here is the javascript

```
$('#firstAPIsubmitButton').click(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: "countryCode.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

        if (result.status.name == "ok") {

            $('#languages').html(result['data'][0]['languages']);
            $('#distance').html(result['data'][0]['distance']);
            $('#countryCode').html(result['data'][0]['countryCode']);
            $('#countryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);

        }
    
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // your error code
    }
 }); 

});
```

here is what i have in HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="firstAPI">
        <button id="firstAPIsubmitButton">first button</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Languages:</td>
                <td id="languages"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Distance:</td>
                <td id="distance"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Country Code:</td>
                <td id="countryCode"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Country Name:</td>
                <td id="countryName"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
   <script type="application/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your resulting JSON looks like this

```
{
    "status":
        {"code":"200",
        "name":"ok",
        "description":"success",
        "returnedIn":"219ms"
        },
    "data":"AT"
}
```

So this code is addressing lots of properties that just dont exist.

```
if (result.status.name == "ok") {
    $('#languages').html(result['data'][0]['languages']);
    $('#distance').html(result['data'][0]['distance']);
    $('#countryCode').html(result['data'][0]['countryCode']);
    $('#countryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
}
```